# If problem A is logspace reducible to 2-SAT, is A in NL?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, space-complexity

I'm trying to prove that some problem, A, is in NL. I have found a logspace reduction from A to 2-SAT - am right in thinking that this is not sufficient to prove that A is in NL?

If so, how does one formally go about proving that a language is in NL - is the only way we can do this by providing some deciding non-deterministic TM for A that only uses logspace?

Comment: In fact, any problem logspace reducible to a problem in NL is itself in NL. The proof is similar to the analogous statement for L.